# “Wrong number of indices in side[],expected '2' ” Error

Tags: c#

I've been         trying to print this code just the way I've written the array, a 3x3 box with     numbers that I will later insert into it. All seems correct but I keep getting this message when I try to write my loop:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[*,*]' to 'int[][]'

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Quadrado Mágico";
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
            Random ran = new Random();
            Console.Clear();

            int[][] quadrado = new int [3,3] { { 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                         { 0, 0, 0 },
                                         { 0, 0, 0 } };

             for(int fila = 0; fila < quadrado.Length; fila++) {
                for(int coluna = 0; coluna < quadrado[fila].Length; coluna++) {
                 Console.WriteLine(quadrado[fila][coluna] + "\t");
                 }
                Console.WriteLine();
             }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please update your question so it is clear where title comes from? (Also there is no need to add "new to C#/programing" to the post as it generally does no add additional information to the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works. You need to change the int[][] to int[,]

Then you need to use GetUpperBound(0) and (1) to get the length of each of the arrays.

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Quadrado Mágico";
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
            Random ran = new Random();
            Console.Clear();

```
        int[ , ] quadrado = new int[3, 3] { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };

        // ... Loop using the GetUpperBounds.
        for (int fila = 0; fila <= quadrado.GetUpperBound(0); fila++)
        {
            for (int coluna = 0; coluna <= quadrado.GetUpperBound(1); coluna++)
            {
                // Display the element at these indexes.
                Console.WriteLine(quadrado[fila, coluna]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot, but can you explain to me what does the GetUpperBound() do here?

Comment: @JamesT.Marshall GetUpperBound(0) gets the length or count of elements in the [ 0, 1 ] the 0 is the index of the array. GetUpperBound(1) is for index 1. Basically [ GetUpperBound(0), GetUpperBound(1) ]. 
If this answered your question please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Quadrado Mágico";
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        Random ran = new Random();
        Console.Clear();

        const int f = 3;
        const int c = 3;

        int[,] quadrado = new int[f, c]
        {
            {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}
        };

        for (int fila = 0; fila < f; fila++)
        {
            for (int coluna = 0; coluna < c; coluna++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(quadrado[fila, coluna] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the following

```
 int[][] quadrado = new int [3,3] { { 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                     { 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 0 } };
```

to

```
int[,] quadrado = new int[3, 3] { { 0, 0, 0 }, 
                                     { 0, 0, 0 },
                                     { 0, 0, 0 } };
```

Comment: Oops sorry. Noticed just the declaration. My bad.